# Ini.ReadString ( ... ) and quotedStr not recognized

Tags: delphi

According to my analysis, Delphi's INI file `ReadString()` function with this sample code:

```
var aDatabase : String;

aDatabase := Ini.ReadString('SectionDatabase', 'Database', 'error');
```

And these sample files:

Inifile #1:

```ini
[SectionDatabase]
Database=MyName
```

Infile #2

```ini
[SectionDatabase]
Database='MyName'
```

returns the same `Database` string and does not recognize if the string is in quotes.

Can I fix this while reading the ini files?

Comment: It looks odd to try to include quotes in a database name, could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: `TIniFile` uses [GetPrivateProfileString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) to read values from the file. The documentation clearly says: *If the string associated with lpKeyName is enclosed in single or double quotation marks, the marks are discarded when the GetPrivateProfileString function retrieves the string.* If you use `TMemIniFile` instead, it won't discard the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't point you to an exact RFC, but that's the generic expectation of the .ini format : you may use quotes, and they are only *required* when you want to specifically include leading or trailing spaces in your value, or for multilines value.

---

If you want a value which includes the quotes, try quoting or escaping them:

```
Database = "'MyName'"
# or
Database = \'MyName\'
```

your parser's documentation should explain how you can include quotes in your values.